# How to see different Kubernetes versions to download from https://storage.googleapis.com?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently using this line in a user_data.sh file

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
```

I've tried to put https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/ in a browser to see which other versions are available but it doesn't work.
If I look for a release number in github and replace v1.21.5 with the updated number in the line above I can download just fine..but is there not a way of just looking at kubernetes releases at https://storage.gpoogleapis.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Use that link in your browser: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/kubernetes-release